# Diseño Responsive no sirve con Tailwind CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive, tailwind

En mi proyecto, estoy usando Tailwind CSS, ya tengo todo el sitio maquetado tanto en Escritorio como en celular, y en ambas resoluciones, el sitio se ve bien (Trabajando con el diseño adaptable de Firefox Developer ) pero al momento de activar la opción Simulador de Toques de firefox, o visualizar mi sitio web directamente desde un celular, el sitio pareciera que no tuviese los estilos que deberia tener, se visualiza como si fuese el sitio en escritorio, no se como solucionar este problema.
[image: Aquí se visualiza correctamente el sitio web, pero solamente desde la vista de diseño adaptable]

[image: Aquí se visualiza de manera incorrecta, esto sucede cuando ya subo mi proyecto a mi hosting y lo visualizo desde celular, o simplemente cuando activo la funcionalidad de "Simulación de Toques" que es la manito que se ve en la vista de diseño adaptable.]

Comment: Como te mencionaron arriba, agrega los CÓDIGOS, no somos adivinos. Respecto al problema, si tienes esto en el head, verdad?: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: Tailwind no detecta sí la página se renderiza en un móvil o no. Se basa en el tamaño de la pantalla. Si lo requieres, puede cambiar los breakpoints https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design#customizing-breakpoints

Answer (score 0):

Tenía el mismo problema. Agregando esto: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`
en el `<head>`, está ok.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp